# Cypress - select element within another element - selector syntax shortcut for `within`

Tags: selector, cypress

I have an element in my HTML which contain one checkbox; something like (the actual output is a bit more complex as we are using React + Material UI. This is however the general idea, one 'container' with only one checkbox within):

```
<span class="..." cy-data="checkbox-container">
  ...
  <checkbox ... />
</span>
```

At the moment to get checkbox in my test I'm using this:

```
 cy.get('[data-cy=checkbox-container]').within(() => {
   cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check();
 })
```

Is there a shorter way to write this?

---

`cy.get('[data-cy=checkbox-container]').get('[type="checkbox"]')` returns the first checkbox found in the complete document; not the one under `checkbox-container`.

`cy.get('[data-cy=checkbox-container] > [type="checkbox"]')` raises a "not found" error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close with the first solution, you can actually use `find()` for this, that searches for the element within the previous search results. So it would look like this:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=checkbox-container]')
   .find('[type="checkbox"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon your values are not dynamic in the checkbox, in that case, you can use

`cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check(['name']) right?`

Did you try this? Or you are trying something different? If so can you please explain a bit more?

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks but the name is dynamic actually.

Comment: how about storing the value and using it? I had the same case but not in checkbox though, I did the same with dynamic drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
        cy.get('.checkbox:contains("checkbox-container")').within(() => {
          cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check();
        });
```

It's obviously very similar to the code you posted but I recently used `selector:contains("specificThingImLookingFor")` to get myself out of a jam.

Sourced from here: https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/6.5.0/commands/querying.html#jquery-selectors